# OpenGL ES 2.0 offline shader compiler for Nvidia Tegra

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

Anyone know how to offline compile OpenGL ES 2.0 shaders for Nvidia Tegra chip? What tool should I use? Thanks.

Comment: btw, asked on the nvidia forums about it. no answer. tegra support is really sh*tty!

Answer (score 4):

not supported (anymore)...

http://developer.nvidia.com/beta-forum#/discussion/436/androidtegra-binary-shaders-example-shader-compiler

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen? http://developer.nvidia.com/tegra-android-development-pack

Comment: not really obvious at first. also i forgot that this exists. thx for the reminder!

Comment: actually, there is NO shader compiler in that pack!

Comment: Sorry, was downloading it when I answered it, took all day, then I found that it was pretty useless unless you want to lean how do to native tegra stuff in c.How about just render monkey? It does open glsl. The Nvidia is a bit of a red hering, cause it shoudn't matter for shaders. And I personally wouldn't target a specifc chipset.

Comment: but what we want is the offline compiler. ABI compatible with nvidia tegra. i doubt that render monkey if at all produces something useable for that platform ... for testing - sure, for offline compiling - no!